# Multiple instance writing on same mounted folder using camel-file component

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, smb, jbossfuse

We have requirement to write to single file using multiple instance of camel interface running simultaneously.
The file is on windows shared file system which has been mounted on JBoss server using SMB.

We are using camel file component to write file from each instance as a local file.
Below is the endpoint URI in camel context

```
file:/fuse/server/location/proc?fileName=abc.csv&fileExist=Append
```

The file generate has no issues when the write is happening from single instance, but in case of multiple instance it add junk characters to the file at random lines.

We are using **JBoss Fuse 6.0.0** and the interface have been written using **camel 2.10** version.

How can this be fixed? Is this the issue with SMB mount or the  interface need to handle it.

Comment: If multiple producers write to the same file well yeah I can see junk being added as they are overwriting each others access. A file is not a object that can be written to at once by many producers that is why for example if you open a csv file in excel and then in notepad and tried to save the notepad version it will complain saying the file is locked. You would need to serialize the access to the file. The file wont be able to handle two producers writing to it without some form of control on who writes first etc. Think file locking.

Comment: I was assuming the camel-file component will take care of it. Does that mean I have to manually handle the same.

Comment: It really depends on the file system. Java probably works better on the open source file systems as their engineers can create byte code specific to that file system they can read the source after all. With SMB MS was forced by courts to open the protocol thus SMB shares are good but there is still a lot of grey area. My suggestion is that instead of these producers sending data to a file make them send it to a queueing component such as seda and let the messages queue one after the other and let seda handle the messages as it will be a FIFO queue. No need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at the source code of the relevant camel component (https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/file) & there isn't any built in support for concurrent access to a single file from multiple JVMs. Concurrent access from a single JVM is handled though.

I think you have two basic options to address your requirement:

1. Write some code to support shared access to a single file. The camel file component looks like it was built with extension in mind, or you could just create a standalone component to do this.
2. As @Namphibian suggests use some queuing system to serialise your writes (though I don't think seda will work, as it doesn't span JVMS.

My solution would be to use ActiveMQ. Each instance of your application would send messages to a single, shared queue. Some other processes would then consume the messages from MQ & write them to disk.

With a single process consuming all MQ messages there would be no concurrent writes to the filesystem.

A more robust solution would to run ActiveMQ in a cluster (possibly with a node in each of your application instances). Look at "JMSXGroupID" to prevent concurrent consumption of messages.

Comment: I agree with Paul. The best thing is to add a messaging system in front and then have another camelcontext pick up the message and write to the file.